# Load Balancing over multiple ISP connections

Tags: linux, networking, routing, load-balancing, linux-networking

I have been trying to implement load balance and fail over on a linux machine having multiple interfaces.

Currently I am using two ISP lines and I wish to split the network traffic such that both of them are used. For this I have made changes to the IP tables and the rules that apply to them.

Following is the Linux Advances Routing and Traffic Control (LARTC) link I am referring http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

Connections do get distributed on both ISP lines. However, it is observed that once a connection is routed over a particular interace, it follows the same route each time.

This is because of the entry that gets made in the routing cache. Load balancing is severely affected due to this phenomenon. I have been clearing the cache at regular intervals which has not made the situation any better.

Comment: What do you mean by "a connection"? Do you mean a TCP connection?

Comment: Not just TCP connection. All types of connections. Ive tried ping, traceroute, FTP, HTTP.

Comment: You should clarify your question with the details of what you tried, what you observed, and what your goal is.

Comment: Think about it a bit, how are you expecting this to work at layer 2,3?  How are you expecting traffic to be able to bounce between links?  In the typical setup the Source address seen by the remote system is going to be the WAN address assigned to one of your links.

Comment: BTW the proper solution is to get a real network allocation, and work with your ISPs and get BGP setup and get true multi-link setup not something that is hacked together on top of NAT.

Comment: You don't get a real answer, because it is hard. As you see, nobody answers: "sorry it is too hard to me", instead they say, "your question is bad". They aren't right, I can be done, but it is not simple.

Comment: I still havent found a solution . How do I make sure the cache entries dont affect the load balancing ? You mentioned there is a solution.